# Sending SmS using Aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-s3, sms

I am implementing an SMS sending server, for that I am using AWS. I have already used their documentation to carry out all the configuration and installation. I have also placed the files and SDK on the AWS server to run the application. But when running the application, I have no error return, but the SMS does not arrive either.
My code is:

```php
public function SendAwsSms(){
    // Passing Aws\Credentials\AssumeRoleCredentialProvider options directly
    $profile = new InstanceProfileProvider();
    $ARN = "arnkeyprovidedfromaws";
    $sessionName = "nameaccessrandom";
    
    $assumeRoleCredentials = new AssumeRoleCredentialProvider([
        'client' => new StsClient([
            'region' => 'sa-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'credentials' => $profile
        ]),
        'assume_role_params' => [
            'RoleArn' => $ARN,
            'RoleSessionName' => $sessionName,
        ],
    ]);

    $provider = CredentialProvider::memoize($assumeRoleCredentials);
    
    $SnSclient = new SnsClient([
        'region' => 'sa-east-1',
        'version'=> 'latest',
        ]);
        
    try {
        $result = $SnSclient->publish([
            "SenderID"=>"Idsender",
            "SMSType"=>"Promocional",
            "Message"=>"Message test",
            "PhoneNumber"=>"+1111111111111",
        ]);
        var_dump($result);
    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        // output error message if fails
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I run the code, no error is displayed, but the SMS does not arrive at the destination.
Can someone show me what's wrong in there? I using PHP, with the CodeIgniter framework, and my system is located in AWS servers.

Comment: did you include your vendor/autoload.php after installing the composer install ?

Comment: and put error_reporting(E_ALL); just in case if you have disabled error reporting

Comment: Yes, the vendor is included after install. And error reporting is enabled, I already put error_reporting(E_ALL) but no one error is showed

Comment: instead of AwsException do \Exception see if that has any entries, if not, extend you try catch other code blocks as well, it could be new object creation that fails

Comment: continues without erros, but the SMS don't send...